# Java app architecture for push notifications service

Tags: java, performance, apple-push-notifications

I have MySQL database table filled occasionally. Expected 1 - 100 rows per second.
I need to develop java app which will monitor this table and when new records are inserted then some Push Notification should be send to Apple server.
All this runs on in house Linux server.
What is the recommended way to do it?
Here is starting point, the way I think to do it ... Do you recommend better way and if yes please give info how:

1. Run tomcat or Jetty server
2. Use Spring Scheduling API to check for new records.
3. Use Java executor framework for concurent push notifications. For exampe if  1000 new messages detected then this should be grouped into 50 chunks each having 20 notifications to be sent. From each chunk(with 20 notifications) will be created Task to be processed.
4. Use  [Java Apple Push Notification Service Provider](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) for sending notifications

So, I am looking for best application architecture to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't use MYSQL as main part of system. rdbms should be used as backup/solid storage.

Messages should be put in some queue(s) (persisted to mysql for example) than messages should be dequeued and sended.

Comment: I agree but at the moment there is existing working app with database. So I need to hook into existing system. Eventually in the future this all will be refactored to use some queue but for now database should remain. Eventually some queue could be introduced and messages would be copied from database to queue. In such case could you give more detail  info about how it would look like.